# Any way to access Windows Phone's stored videos via C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I just want to know if there is any method to get videos stored on the phone via a WP7/8 C# app ?

I was surprised to discover that this is impossible to do with the PhotoChooserTask. Only photos can be selected. I want photos AND videos.

How can I do this.. ?

Thanks

Comment: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1897833-video-chooser-task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with the current SDK. However, according to Microsoft, it is high on the priorities list. A petition for this feature is [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1897833-video-chooser-task).